# Magento Upgrade from 1.10.0.1 to 1.14.8 504 gateway timeout

Tags: enterprise-1.10

We are upgrading Magento from 1.10.0.1 to 1.11.0.2 now.
We have the below environment. 
1) PHP = 5.6.32
2) Mysql = Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB
3) Ngnix = 1.12.2
4) centos = centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64
We are using AWS environment where EC2 instance is used for application and RDS instance for database.

After I copy file for Magento 1.11.0.2. While upgrading database via web, I am getting 504 gateway timeout. When I checked DB I can see some of database scripts are executed. It suggest me that My database connection is getting lost. How to reslove this. I have already updated PHP max_execution_time to 300. and request_terminate_timeout to 300, but still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server related error and you will need to contact your hosting provider to have them resolve it for you.